# replace specific characters from variable - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a variable with value `test1/test2/test3` in my script. I want to return `test1?test2?test3`. How can I make this possible??

How can I make this possible??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: try not forget that jQuery is just a javascript framework. And you shouldn't try to solve every task with it. (http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: I am using it as my core and 'm a beginner.. Thats y... `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the string.replace() function and use a regular expression as the first parameter specifying you want to replace the string your searching for globally.

Try this:

```
var str = "test1/test2/test3";
str = str.replace(/\//g,"?");
alert(str);
```

Comment: what about `str.replace("/", "?")`

Comment: @blasteralfred: that will only replace the first instance of "/" and you would get "test1?test2/test3"

Comment: my editor is showing errors.. it returns `//g,"?");` as faded.. I think it is taking the code after // as comment or something else... `:P`

Comment: @blasteralfred: I wouldn't worry so much about what my editor was telling me... try it out in a browser. You can see it in action and working here: http://jsfiddle.net/k6WzS/

Comment: yea dude.. it wors well :) ..  sometimes editors sucks... `:P`

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use a Regular Expression with replace to match all values of "/"

Here is a link for using [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

```
newStr = strVar.replace(/\//g,"?");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 'test1/test2/test3'
x.replace(/\//g, "?");
```

Check example http://jsfiddle.net/XPHSG/